# Need help in improving the speed of my code for duplicate columns removal in Python

Tags: list, python-2.7, dictionary, duplicates

I have written a code to take a text file as input and print only the variants which repeat more than once. By variants I mean, chr positions in the text file.

The input file looks like this:

> chr1  1048989 1048989 A   G   intronic    C1orf159            0.16    rs4970406
>   chr1  1049083 1049083 C   A   intronic    C1orf159            0.13    rs4970407
>   chr1  1049083 1049083 C   A   intronic    C1orf159            0.13    rs4970407
>   chr1  1113121 1113121 G   A   intronic    TTLL10          0.13    rs12092254

As you can see, rows 2 and 3 repeat. I'm just taking the first 3 columns and seeing if they are the same. Here, chr1 1049083 1049383 repeat in both row2 and row3. So I print out saying that there is one duplicate and it's position.

I have written the code below. Though it's doing what I want, it's quite slow. It takes me about 5 min to run on a file which have 700,000 rows. I wanted to know if there is a way to speed things up.

Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
""" takes in a input file and 
    prints out only the variants that occur more than once """

import shlex
import collections

rows = open('variants.txt', 'r').read().split("\n")
# removing the header and storing it in a new variable
header = rows.pop()
indices = []

for row in rows:
    var = shlex.split(row)
    indices.append("_".join(var[0:3]))

dup_list = []
ind_tuple = collections.Counter(indices).items()

for x, y in ind_tuple:
    if y>1:
        dup_list.append(x)

print dup_list    
print len(dup_list)
```

Note: In this case the entire row2 is a duplicate of row3. But this is not necessarily the case all the time. Duplicate of chr positions (first three columns) is what I'm looking for.

EDIT: 
Edited the code as per the suggestion of damienfrancois. Below is my new code:

```
f = open('variants.txt', 'r')
indices = {}
for line in f:
    row = line.rstrip()   
    var = shlex.split(row)
    index = "_".join(var[0:3])
    if indices.has_key(index):
        indices[index] = indices[index] + 1
    else:
        indices[index] = 1

dup_pos = 0        
for key, value in indices.items():
    if value > 1:
        dup_pos = dup_pos + 1

print dup_pos
```

I used, time to see how long both the code takes.

My original code:

```
time run remove_dup.py 
14428 
CPU times: user 181.75 s, sys: 2.46 s,total: 184.20 s 
Wall time: 209.31 s
```

Code after modification:

```
time run remove_dup2.py 
14428
CPU times: user 177.99 s, sys: 2.17 s, total: 180.16 s
Wall time: 222.76 s
```

I don't see any significant improvement in the time.

Comment: Is command-line an option? I use `sort` and `uniq` on multi-hundred thousand line files... `sort variants.txt | uniq`  If the lines are already in order such that duplicates are next to each other, you can just use `uniq` without sorting... If this is feasible, I can also post an answer that just looks at the first three fields.

Comment: I agree that command line is a faster way of doing this. `grep -v "#" variants.txt |cut -f 1,2,3 | sort | uniq -d | wc -l` actually gives me the same output too. But I wanted to try it out in python.

Comment: I understand. Sometimes it is hard to tell if people are interested in a solution or learning via the question. Both are admirable!

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

- do not read the whole file at once ; read line by line and process it on the fly ; you'll save memory operations
- let indices be a default dict and increment the value at key "_".join(var[0:3]) ; this saves the costly (guessing here, should use a [profiler](http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html)) collections.Counter(indices).items() step
- try [pypy](http://pypy.org/) or a [python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cython) [compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shed_Skin)
- split your data in as many subsets as your computer has cores, apply the program to each subset in parallel then merge the results

HTH

Comment: Hi.. based on your suggestions, I changed my code. But I did not see significant improvement. I included my new code in my question. 

I did not do parallel computing though, I'm not good at it. Any suggestions to improve the speed? Thanks!

Comment: You can replace `indices.items()` with `indices.iteritems()` so it does not create the full list in memory. BTW you do not need to be good at parallel computing to do parallel computing :) Just sort and split your file in two parts with your favorite editor or with `split` (make sure that the end of the first one is totally different from the start of the second one) and launch the program once on each file in the background. Then add both answers.

Comment: Thanks for `indices.iteritems()` tip. +1 for that. It did not improve my performance in this case, but seems always best to use it instead of items().

Answer (score 0):

A big time sink is probably the `if..has_key()` portion of the code. In my experience, try-except is a lot faster...

```
f = open('variants.txt', 'r')
indices = {}
for line in f: 
    var = line.split()
    index = "_".join(var[0:3])
    try:
        indices[index] += 1
    except KeyError:
        indices[index] = 1
f.close()
dup_pos = 0        
for key, value in indices.items():
    if value > 1:
        dup_pos = dup_pos + 1

print dup_pos
```

Another option there would be replace the four `try except` lines with:

```
indices[index] = 1 + indices.get(index,0)
```

This approach only tells how many lines of the lines are duplicated, and not how many times they are repeated. (So if one line is duped 3x, then it will say one...)

If you are *only* trying to count the duplicates and not delete or note them, you could tally the lines of the file as you go, and compare this to the length of the `indices` dictionary, and the difference is the number of dupe lines (instead of looping back through and re-counting). This might save a little time, but gives a different answer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

f = open('variants.txt', 'r')
indices = {}
total_len=0
for line in f: 
    total_len +=1
    var = line.split()
    index = "_".join(var[0:3])
    indices[index] = 1 + indices.get(index,0)
f.close()  
print "Number of duplicated lines:", total_len - len(indices.keys())
```

I'd be curious to hear what your benchmarks are for code that does *not* include the `has_key()` test...

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. I did do the edits like u suggested. But it did improve my speed! :( And I will preferably need to know how many times they repeat as well, for future purposes.